# Codeigniter multi-lingual application storing data

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, multilingual

I am working on an application where the framework of choice is Codeigniter (due to team's skill set etc). The application has forms that need to be filled in both English and French. The client wants to make sure that both forms are completed before a certain action can be completed.

I know that looking at documentation, I can build an app that uses Language library to toggle the labels etc for the forms, but how would I go about building the backend so that both english and french forms are completed properly and stored with the database.

One solution that I have in mind is to create a table (for example: Employee) with both english and french columns

So:

```
Employee:
- first_name_en
- last_name_en
- first_name_fr
- last_name_fr
```

the other idea is to store english and french separately, but then query for reports becomes an issue.

I was wondering if anyone else has tackled this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say to create separate tables for each language.

If you look at the architecture of the Language library, each language file is stored separately (language/en, language/fr, etc). This is so that you can pull in whichever file you need based on the user's preference that is viewing the page.

If you store your data separately, you just need to query the correct table based on the user's preference. If I want to view in french, then you query the `employee_fr` table - and for english, query the `employee_en` table.